# Pixi3d mesh with texture is flipped when projecting on a PIXI.RenderTexture?

Tags: webgl, pixi.js, render-to-texture

I am using PIXI to render 2d elements and PIXI3d library for 3d elements. In my current project I have to draw a 3d cube rotating on 2d background and generate an mp4 as an output. to create mp4 i am using rendertexture to generate each frame of the animation. But in doing so the cube is getting flipped when the container is mapped on a render texture.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pixi3d-rendertextureissue-yxmg6g?file=/src/index.js)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.